# moov atom not found OP

Tags: python, opencv, video, ocr, mp4

Problem: "moov atom not found" error when processing video using OpenCV and pytesseract.

I am developing a program to process videos using OpenCV and pytesseract. My goal is to extract text with timecodes from videos on the YouTube platform. However, when attempting to process the video using the provided code, I encountered the "moov atom not found" error.

I have verified that the video link is correct and the video plays without any issues. I have also checked my internet connection and updated the OpenCV and pytesseract libraries to the latest versions. However, the problem persists.

I have explored potential solutions, including releasing resources from cv2.VideoWriter and cv2.VideoCapture before loading the video, but it did not resolve the error.

I am reaching out to the community for assistance and recommendations. I would like to understand why the "moov atom not found" error occurs and how I can successfully process the video and extract text with timecodes.

I appreciate any help and guidance in resolving this issue.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import os
import urllib
from urllib import request


# Set the path to the Tesseract OCR executable (if required)
# pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

# Function to process video and extract text with timecodes
def extract_text_from_video(youtube_url, output_file):
    # Загрузка видео с YouTube
    youtube_video = urllib.request.urlopen(youtube_url)
    video_bytes = youtube_video.read()
    video_bytes_array = bytearray(video_bytes)

    # Create a temporary video file
    with open('temp_video.mp4', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(video_bytes_array)

    # Opening a video file with OpenCV
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('temp_video.mp4')

    # Get the total length of the videoо
    total_frames = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    fps = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

    # Create a file to save text with timecodes
    output = open(output_file, 'w')

    # Processing each frame of the video
    for frame_num in range(total_frames):
        # Extract frame from video
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()
        if not ret:
            break

        # Convert frame to grayscale
        gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Recognize text on a frame with Tesseract OCR
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray_frame, lang='eng')

        # If text is recognized, save it and the corresponding timecode to a file
        if text:
            timestamp = frame_num / fps
            output.write(f"Тайм-код: {timestamp:.2f}\n")
            output.write(f"Текст: {text}\n\n")

    # Closing files and freeing resources
    video_capture.release()
    output.close()

    print("Извлечение текста завершено!")
    print(f"Результаты сохранены в файле: {output_file}")

    # Delete temporary video file
    os.remove('temp_video.mp4')


# Paste the link to the YouTube video and specify the path to the file to save the results
youtube_url = 'YoutubevideoURL'
output_file = 'extracted_text.txt'

# Extract text with timecodes from video
extract_text_from_video(youtube_url, output_file)
```

I tried running the modified code to extract text with timecodes from a YouTube video using OpenCV and pytesseract. I expected the code to successfully process the video, recognize the text, and save the results in the specified output file. However, when running the code, an error occurred related to the "moov atom not found".

Comment: welcome. [mre] required. focus your question.

Comment: ...@eternal_despair "moov atom not found" means your input to OpenCV is not a valid MP4 or MOV. Solution: Make sure `youtube_url` is a url to **video file** not a url to a **web page**.